# If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show that the set of points fixed by $f$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Armstrong's Basic Topology and this is exercise 2.13. I'm not sure how to approach. I'm thinking: let the set of points fixed by $f$ be $V$, and we need to prove that $V^c$ in the image of $f$ is open. Using the fact that $f$ is continuous, we can in turn show that $f^{-1}(V^c)$ is open, which relies on $V$ being closed. So my logic is going kind of cyclic. Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: You should specify that f is continuous from R to R. Remember that all we can see is the screen, not the book.

Comment: @user254665 Sorry for the confusion. I thought that's included in the title?

Comment: Sorry. I usually breeze past the title,You are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider the function $h(x)=x-f(x)$. How can you apply the idea of inverse image to this function?

Comment: I see! First of all, since $x$ and $f(x)$ are continuous, $h(x)$ is also continuous. Then, the image of the set of points that are fixed by $f$ is exactly $\{0\}$, which is closed; then by continuity of $h$, the pre-image of the set $\{0\}$ under $h$ is also closed, as desired. How does this look?

Comment: Perfect. Good job.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_n$ is a sequence in the fixed point set and $x_n\to x.$ We want to show $x$ is in the fixed point set. By continuity, $f(x_n) \to f(x).$ Since $f(x_n) = x_n$ for all $n,$ we have $x_n \to f(x).$ So $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \to f(x).$ By uniqueness of limits, $f(x) = x$ and $x$ is in the fixed point set as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Show more generally that if $f,g : X \to Y$ are continuous maps from a topological space $X$ into a *Hausdorff* space $Y$, then $E:=\{x \in X : f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a closed subset $X$. The reason is that $\{(y,y) : y \in Y\}$ is closed in $Y \times Y$, hence the preimage of $(f,g) : X \to Y \times Y$ is closed in $X$. But this preimage  equals $E$.

Answer (score 1):

In every topological space $X$ and a Hausdorff space $Y$ the set $A:=\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is always closed in $X$, where $f,g:X\to Y$ are continuous.

For if $x\in X\setminus A$ then $f(x)\neq g(x)$ and there exist $U,V\subseteq Y$ open such that $f(x)\in U,g(x)\in V$ and $V\cap U=\emptyset$. Then $x\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)\subseteq X\setminus A$. This shows $X\setminus A$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

A topoloical space $X$ is a Hausdorff space (synonym $T_2$ space) iff whenever $p,q\in X$ with $p\ne q$, there are open sets $U_p,U_q$ with $p\in U_p,\;q\in U_q\;$ and $U\cap U_q=\emptyset.$ THEOREM : If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space and $f:X\to Y,  \; g:X\to Y$ are continuous then $\{p\in X :f(p)=g(p)\}$ is a closed subset of $X.$ (Proof below). Observe that $R$ is $T_2$ because if $p.q\in R$ with $p\ne q$ , let $r=|p-1|/2$ and let $U_p=(p-r,p+r),\;$  $U_q=(q-r,q+r).$ So if $f:R\to R$ is continuous, let  $g=id_R$ (that is, $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in R$ ). Since $g$ is (obviously) continuous, so $\{x \in R:f(x)=x\}=\{x \in R :f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed in $R.$ Of course in $R$ we have algebraic properties related to the topology,so that the answer of Alex S is a lot easier. In general we do not always have a useful algebra to relate to the topology.....   PROOF OF THEOREM: By contradiction. Suppose $q\in Cl_X \{p :f(p)=g(p)\}$ but $f(x)\ne g(x).$ In $Y$ there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $f(q)\in U$ and $g(q)\in V.$ In $X $, the point  $q$ has  nbhds $U^*  ,V^*$ such that $\{f(x) :x\in U^*\}\subset U$ and $\{g(x) :x\in v^*\}\subset V.$ But then $ W=U^*\cap V^*$ is a nbhd of $q$ which is disjoint from $\{p :f(p)=g(p)\}$... (...because $U\cap V$ is empty and $p\in W\to (f(p)\in U\land g(p)\in V)$ ...)... but this contradicts $q\in Cl_X \{p:f(p)=g(p)\}$....... Another result from this theorem is that if continuous $f:R\to R,\; g:R\to R$ agree on the rationals then $f=g$ because $\{r :f(r)=g(r)\}=Cl_R\{r:f(r)=g(r)\}\supset Cl_RQ=R.$